# Updating database from a dynamic jtable

Tags: java, sql, database, jtable

I am trying to update a database from a dynamic JTable. Here is my code

```
try {
   //open connection...
   conn = javaConnect.ConnectDb();
   //select the qualifications table row for the selected staffID
   String sql2 = "select * from QualificationsTable where qualID =" + theRowID;
   pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
   ResultSet rs2 = pStmt.executeQuery();
   //check if QualificationsTable has content on that row...
   if (rs2.next()) {
      //it has content update...
      //get the model for the qual table...
      DefaultTableModel tModel = (DefaultTableModel) qualTable.getModel();
      for (int i = 0; i < tModel.getRowCount(); i++) {

         //get inputs from the tables
         String qualification = tModel.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
         String yearAttained = tModel.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();

         //sql query for updating qualifications table...
         String sql3 = "update QualificationsTable set qualifications = ?, yearAttained = ? where qualID = ?";
         pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
         //set the pareameters...
         pStmt.setString(1, qualification);
         pStmt.setString(2, yearAttained);
         pStmt.setInt(3, theRowID);
         //execute the prepared statement...
         pStmt.execute();
         // dbStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES('"+item+"','"+quant+"','"+unit+"','"+tot+"')");
      }
      //close connection
      conn.close();

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Qualifications updated successfully!", "Success", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   } else {
      //it doesnt have content insert...
      //get the model for the qual table...
      DefaultTableModel tModel = (DefaultTableModel) qualTable.getModel();

      for (int i = 0; i < tModel.getRowCount(); i++) {                    
          //System.out.println(tModel.getSelectedColumn()+tModel.getSelectedRow());

          //get inputs from the tables
          String qualification = tModel.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
          String yearAttained = tModel.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();

          //sql query for storing into QualificationsTable
          String sql3 = "insert into QualificationsTable (qualifications,yearAttained,qualID) "
                   + "values (?,?,?)";
          pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
          //set the parameters...
          pStmt.setString(1, qualification);
          pStmt.setString(2, yearAttained);
          pStmt.setInt(3, theRowID);
          //execute the prepared statement...
          pStmt.execute();

       }
       //close connection
       conn.close();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Qualifications saved successfully!", "Success", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(StoreInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } catch(NullPointerException nfe){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(infoParentTab, "Please, always hit the Enter button to effect your changes on the table", "USER ERROR!", ERROR_MESSAGE);

 }

 } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(infoParentTab, "You must select a Staff from the Browser...", "USER ERROR!", ERROR_MESSAGE);
 }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

what i am actually trying to do is to use a table linked to a database to store qualifications of staff in a company. now each entry in the qualifications database is referenced to the staffID in the staffs database through qualID.

so when i store the qualification on the table, it also records the staff that has the qualification. this should enable me retrieve a particular staff's qualifications from the database when need.

the segment for inserting into the database if empty works fine (i.e. the else... segment). but the update segment (i.e. the if... segment) is faulty in the sense that the code uses the last row on the JTable  to populate all the rows in the database table instead of replicating all the new changes into the database table when update is need.

i have tried everything i could to no avail. please i need much help in this...time is not on my side. tnx guys in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a `CachedRowSet` to back up the `JTable's` model. You'll be able to view, insert and update data easily.

Here's the tutorial: [Using JDBC with GUI API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcswing.html)

Comment: please i dont really know how i would implement this CachedRowSet...this is just a segment of my code...i v already done a large amount of db stuff using the normal resultset method...i hope this doesnt mean i will have to start afresh?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. I just gave you a link to a tutorial that creates a `JTable/CachedRowSet` program to perform operations on a database table.

Comment: alright thanks bro...please dont be annoyed i am just frustrated :(

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not annoyed. It's just easier to offer you a link to a properly formed program than to go through your code to fix things. You're mixing data access code and GUI, which would be a big no-no in any real program.

Comment: kayaman pls am sorry if am disturbing...i have taken my time to go through the tutorial and i have discovered that i really need to remodel a lot of things which i dont have the time to do :( pls can u just look at my code a bit especially the if(rs.next()) segment. i also dont understand what you mean by that i am mixing data access code and GUI...tnx a lot bro